# Why the Artin braid group is a quotient of the corresponding reflection group?

Tags: reflection, coxeter-groups, braid-groups

[image]

I am reading the book "Lecture Notes on Cluster Algebras" written by Robert J. Marsh. On page 46, I don't know why the Artin braid group is a quotient of the corresponding reflection group? Who can give me an examle? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As it stands, $W$ is a quotient of $B$ .

Comment: do you mean  $W\cong B/{\langle \sigma_{i}^{2}-e \rangle}$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.